# Rank-1 matrix with two dependent rows?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, rank-1-matrices

I want to know what could be the possible rank of a matrix, which is constructed from a same vector but have two repeating rows.
Lets say I have a vector $$x=\begin{bmatrix}1 &a &1& b\end{bmatrix}^T$$ of complex quantities $a \&b \in C$and if I define a rank-1 hermitian matrix $X=xx^T$, there will be two dependent rows in the matrix (1st and third rows)

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &a^*& 1& b^*\\
a &aa^*& a& ab^*\\
1 &a^*& 1& b^*\\
b &ba^*& 1& bb^*\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am wondering if the presence of two dependent rows will effect the rank in some way or will i still get a rank-1 matrix after getting the solution (i.e., putting the values of a and b). Question might sound silly but my derivation is stuck on this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The rank of a matrix is equal to :

 - the dimension of the image of the endomorphism this matrix represents

 - the dimension of the span of its column vectors

 - the dimension of the span of its row vectors

Comment: Something seems funny with your multiplication.  How is $\mathsf{A}_{12} = \mathsf{A}_{21} = a$ but $\mathsf{A}_{22} = aa^*$?

Comment: @DanUznanski I agree, there was a type, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

A rank one matrix is a matrix in which the dimension of the vector space, spanned by the rows, is *one*.

This means that for any two pairs of rows in a rank one matrix, one will be a multiple of the other.